# how to get accurate date and time of timestamp column in oracle 11g?

Tags: sql

I am executing below two select statements. But it will shown difference.

1. `select TO_CHAR(AUTHORIZE_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')|| 'T' || TO_CHAR(AUTHORIZE_DATE,'HH24:MM:SS') from table_name`

And output is: `2017-02-21T05:02:58`

2. `select AUTHORIZE_DATE from table_name`

And output is: `2/21/2017 5:35:58`

**required output:** 2017-02-21T05:35:58 .

But I am not able to getting accurate time. Please help on this issue? Here column data type is Timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are so close, just change to this: (minute is `MI`, and month is `MM`)

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(authorize_date,'YYYY-MM-DD')|| 'T' || TO_CHAR(authorize_date,'HH24:MI:SS') 
FROM table_name;
```

For more information about TO_CHAR parameter for date type, you could [go here](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php)

Comment: This appears to be the same query as in the OP.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen for parameter of datetime, in oracle minute is `MI` instead of `MM` for month

Comment: Nice catch, didn't see that +1

Comment: Thanks for all quick help:)

Comment: @srinunivas You should mark **mathguy**'s answer as right answer. That uses all potential features of `TO_CHAR` and have cleaner code then in my answer.

Comment: @PhamX.Bach sorry i am new user. i don't know process i am consider your answer.your answer more help me Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The right way to get that format is this (all with one `TO_CHAR()`, just use all its features):

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss') as now from dual;

NOW
-------------------
2017-03-01T22:49:56
```

Comment: ah, very nice way to concatenate those strings. Could you refer the name of that technique (or link where you learn it) plz?

Comment: @PhamX.Bach It's in the Oracle documentation of the `TO_CHAR` function: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212  Quote: Punctuation and Character Literals in Datetime Format Models 

You can include these characters in a date format model:

•Punctuation such as hyphens, slashes, commas, periods, and colons


• **Character literals, enclosed in double quotation marks**


These characters appear in the return value in the same location as they appear in the format model.

Comment: Thank you for that link. Have a nice day!